# How do I make the rest of the text in this navigation bar appear inline with the logo

Tags: html, css

So I have been trying to get the text for my navigation bar to line up with my image logo.  Any ideas how I can fix my code?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

li {
float: left;
}

li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 25px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
font-style: normal;
opacity: .5;
}

li a:hover {
color: white;
opacity: 1;
font-weight: 500;
transition: all .7s;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px black;
}

.logo-image{
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
border-radius: 50%;
margin-top: 6px;
image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges; /* Firefox */
image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges; /* Ope[enter image description here][1]ra */
image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; /* Webkit (non-standard naming) */
image-rendering: crisp-edges;   
}
```

Comment: Please post the result of your code so that it will be easier to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add the logo or img as list item and add display: flex; to the ul, also to center it vertically add align-items: center;